# Why entity framework need generate local query view? How about Nhibernate?

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate

I found a very interesting in page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx

Here you can see during query stages, there is an stage named "Generating views" will cost a lot. Even though EF provides some method to pre-compile  it, but if you have many query without pre-compile you still may get problems.

You can find How to: Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

And here, you can see query without pre-generate will cost twice time. So that means it does cost a lot. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/08/06/isolating-performance-with-precompiled-pre-generated-views-in-the-entity-framework-4.aspx

So I have a question, why EF design this stage? And does NHibernate also have this stage? If true, how about it performance in Nhibernate?

Comment: It's only performed once per app domain so no matter how expensive it is (< 1 second in that linked article), it won't have any real impact except on very short-lived apps. The views are used to map the internal query structure to the appropriate store language (most likely T-SQL)

Comment: @Basic Yes, it is only run once, not big problem, but interesting. You can see there is one stage called "Preparing the query". I think this stage is the step you mentioned to build the query SQL. In fact if I do the design, I prefer to put all the effort in the "Preparing the query", not to generate the view. In fact I am not sure the "view" here is a real database view or an metadata view. I did not get any further information now.

Comment: The view here has nothing to do with a SQL view, @Basic has it exactly right its used for doing the query translation.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor If so, that means EF is different with NH at this point? Because you can see the SQL that NH generate do not use any SQL View. Am I right? Do you know why EF design using SQL View? Why not just generate in the SQL like NH?

Comment: @Coofucoo EF Generating views != SQL Views

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Could you explain more about EF generating views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF views have nothing to do with SQL views - EF views are mapping transformation compiled into executable code. EF use these transformation to convert its query representation into target SQL representation. The reason for this compilation is performance of the whole application - you need to invest time to initialization but all your subsequent queries and updates will use compiled code instead of some lookup in EDM. If you don't need to modify mapping at runtime you can even pre-compile those views during compilation of your application.

EF views are used for query preparation (transforming one representation into another) but the query preparation must be done for each unique query. In EF 4 this preparation is not cached unless you manually use [Compiled query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx). In EF 4.5 and 5.0 (.NET 4.5) all queries are automatically "compiled" = there is the cache and each unique query is really prepared only once. Subsequent execution of the same query use compiled version from the cache.

You can read more about performance and EF 5.0 in [this beginner guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is clear for me. But do you anything about NHibernate? Is this EF view a better solution that EF compare with NH?

Comment: I don't know much about NH internal implementation but I know NH has something called named queries - HQL queries defined in markup which are parsed and compiled only once when you start using NH. EF uses compiled queries in the same way.